# D3 V3 multiple buttons with seperate events in single node in typescript

Tags: d3.js

i'am creating a new tree with some texts in node with few buttons, i'am using foreignObject for creating node with buttons, ui comes fine but buttons don't have the events?
Any pointers on how to achieve different events with buttons with text inside them?

i tried creating multiple rects to get the events but with multiple rects texts don't show up in rects

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: got the solution by creating multiple rects inside main rect container